# Update database with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to update my database using a dropdown menu
Most ajax i can find is to retireve data. Can someone please help.

My php updatestatus.php page is

```
include 'includes/session.php';
include 'includes/db_connection.php';
include 'includes/functions.php';

$status = $_POST['status'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE orders SET
        status = '$status'
        WHERE id = $id";
```

And my select box in order.php is

```
<select name="status" id="id" onchange="updateStatus((this.value),<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)">
   <option value="<?php echo $row['status']; ?>"><?php echo $row['status']; ?></option>
   <option value="Order Placed">Order Placed</option>
   <option value="Processing">Processing</option>
   <option value="Dispatched">Dispatched</option>
</select>
```

And my JavaScript in order.php is

```
function updateStatus(status, id){
var url = "updatestatus.php";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // branch for native XMLHttpRequest object
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
    req.open('POST', url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.send(data);

}else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // branch for IE/Windows ActiveX version
    req = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
    if (req) {
        req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
        req.open('POST', url, true);
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.send(data);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use jQuery.

Comment: Are you having problems sending the request? or processing the request?

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
 req.send(data);
```

where is `data` being defined?  It must be a url encoded string containing your `id` and `status`.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest) came up when I searched.

Answer (score 0):

Define `data` as:

```
var data = "status="+status+"&id="+id;
```

Also change your sql as:

```
$sql = "UPDATE orders SET
        status = '".$status."'
        WHERE id =". $id;
```